# Use of the Kafka KStream through() method - Understanding the assignment of instances to partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am having some trouble to use the KStream `through()` method to ensure that messages are distributed to the correct partition.

Here is some background. I have a kafka stream application that listens for CustomerEvent on the inTopic and writes CatalogEvent on the outTopic:

```
inTopic ---> MY_KAFKA_STREAM_APPLICATION ---> outTopic
```

- On the inTopic, the key and value are (AccountId, CustomerEvent).
- On the outTopic, key and value are (CatalogId, CatalogEvent)

I am using the KStream `transform()` method to convert a CustomerEvent into a CatalogEvent. I need to use `transform()` because a CatalogEvent depends on previous CustomerEvents sharing the same CatalogId I've seen in the past, so there will be a state store involved.

Here is how I am initializing my state store. I will be querying the state store by CatalogId to retrieve information about previous CustomerEvents sharing the same CatalogId I've seen before.

```
StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, MyAggregator>> catalogStore = 
     Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("myStore"), Serdes.String(), aggregatorSerde)
           .withLoggingEnabled(new HashMap<>());

builder.addStateStore(catalogStore);
```

Here is how I am setting up my topology:

```
builder.stream("inTopic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), customerEventSerde))
    .selectKey((k, customerEvent) -> customerEvent.getCatalogId())
    .through("bycatalogid", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), customerEventSerde))
    .transform(()-> new MyTransformer("myStore"), "myStore")
    .to("outTopic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), catalogEventSerde));
```

I need to make sure that all CustomerEvents that share the same CatalogId end up on the same partition. So that is why I am using `selectKey()` to change the key from AccountId to CatalogId and I use the `through()` method.

I am doing a test with 2 partitions for my topics, 2 instances of my kafka stream application and 1 kafka server.

I am using the following command to see how my instances are assigned to each partition:

**GOOD ASSIGNMENT CASE**

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --group my_application_group --bootstrap-server 192.168.92.118:9092
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.


TOPIC          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG CONSUMER-ID
bycatalogid    1          -               0               -   consumer1/192.168.92.118 
inTopic        1          9               9               0   consumer1/192.168.92.118
bycatalogid    0          5               5               0   consumer2/192.168.92.29
inTopic        0          12              12              0   consumer2/192.168.92.29
```

Sometimes the assignment is good as shown above. All the consumers are assigned correctly. Instance running on 192.168.92.118 is assigned to partition1 and the one running on 192.168.92.29 is assigned to partition0. Also, I can see that all CustomerEvents sharing the same CatalogId are sent to the same partition.

However, sometimes when I restart my instances, the assignment of instances to partition is wrong:

**BAD ASSIGNMENT CASE**

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --group my_application_group --bootstrap-server 192.168.92.118:9092
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.

TOPIC          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG CONSUMER-ID
bycatalogid    0          11              11              0   consumer1/192.168.92.118
bycatalogid    1          3               3               0   consumer1/192.168.92.118
inTopic        0          18              18              0   consumer2/192.168.92.29
inTopic        1          12              12              0   consumer2/192.168.92.29
```

The above assignment makes no sense at all. The instance running on 192.168.92.118 is listening only on topic bycatalogid and the other instance on 192.168.92.29 is listening only on topic inTopic. How is that possible ?

Also, for debugging purposes, I have implemented an REST api in my service where I can send an HTTP GET request with a CatalogId to retrieve what is in my kafka store. I am accessing my kafka store like this:

```
ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, MyAggregator> catalogStore 
    = streams.store("myStore", QueryableStoreTypes.<String, MyAggregator>keyValueStore());
```

The above throws the following exception if it is executed on the instance that is listening only on the inTopic partition.

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: The state store, myStore, may have migrated to another instance.
```

Is there something I need to do to ensure that I don't get the **BAD ASSIGNMENT CASE**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Both cases are valid. Your input topic and through topic both have 2 partitions. Thus, 4 tasks are created and each task is an independent unit of processing and can be assigned independently form all other tasks.

There is no reason why one instance needs to process partitions from two different topics.

For interactive queries: the above it the reason why stores can be hosted on different instances. (Cf. https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html)